# Releasing Objects In an NSOperation

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I've subclassed NSOperation and add instances of it to an NSOperationQue when I need it.
In the main function of the NSOperation I create an AudioBufferList and then free it when I'm done.

In the memory allocation section of instruments it's showing that instances of these AudioBufferLists are constantly climbing. The living number of bytes constantly climbs and the mdata part of the buffer appears to be the culprit.

This is a segment of my code.

Am I correctly releasing my bufferlist or could instruments be reporting incorrectly?

```
-(void)main

{
//autorelase stuff in here



        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 


  AudioBufferList *bufferList;

            bufferList = (AudioBufferList *) malloc (
                                                     sizeof (AudioBufferList) + sizeof (AudioBuffer) * (1)
                                                     );

            if (NULL == bufferList) {NSLog (@"*** malloc failure for allocating bufferList memory"); return;}

            // initialize the mNumberBuffers member
            bufferList->mNumberBuffers = 2;

            // initialize the mBuffers member to 0
            AudioBuffer emptyBuffer = {0};
            size_t arrayIndex;
            for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < 2; arrayIndex++) {
                bufferList->mBuffers[arrayIndex] = emptyBuffer;
            }

            // set up the AudioBuffer structs in the buffer list
            bufferList->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels  = 1;
            bufferList->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize    = numberofframestoread * sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
            bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData            = (AudioUnitSampleType*)calloc(numberofframestoread, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));

            if (2 == 2) {
                bufferList->mBuffers[1].mNumberChannels  = 1;
                bufferList->mBuffers[1].mDataByteSize    = numberofframestoread * sizeof (AudioUnitSampleType);
                bufferList->mBuffers[1].mData            = (AudioUnitSampleType*)calloc(numberofframestoread, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));

            }


            AudioUnitSampleType *inSamplesChannelLeft=bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;
            AudioUnitSampleType *inSamplesChannelRight=bufferList->mBuffers[1].mData;


// do stuff with buffer here

free(bufferList);

bufferlist=nil;

[pool release]

}
```

Comment: `* (2 - 1)` ?? Also you are leaking an autorelease pool when you return if `NULL == bufferList`. You should post your struct declaration.

Comment: well spotted. Also , what struct declaration are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `mData` is the culprit, make sure you free those as well since you allocate them as calloc.

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

const size_t nBuffers = 2;
AudioBufferList *bufferList;

bufferList = (AudioBufferList *) malloc (
                                         sizeof (AudioBufferList) + sizeof (AudioBuffer) * (nBuffers - 1)
                                         );

if (NULL == bufferList) {NSLog (@"*** malloc failure for allocating bufferList memory"); [pool drain]; return;}
// initialize the mNumberBuffers member
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = nBuffers;

//...
bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData            = (AudioUnitSampleType*)calloc(numberofframestoread, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));
//...
bufferList->mBuffers[1].mData            = (AudioUnitSampleType*)calloc(numberofframestoread, sizeof(AudioUnitSampleType));
//...

//Free mData here
for(size_t i = 0; i < nBuffers; i++)
    free(bufferList->mBuffers[i].mData);
free(bufferList);
[pool drain];
```

Comment: Ok I see. If I had of just malloc'd them would it have been enough just to call free on the bufferlist alone & if so why?

Comment: Any call to allocate memory, `calloc`/`malloc`/`valloc`, requires a call to `free` so in this situation you would always need to loop over the number of buffers and free all of the `mData`

Comment: cheers thanks. In that case the Mixerhost sample project leaks its buffer list too because that only free the bufferlist and not its mData members

Comment: No it looks like Mixerhost does not allocate memory for mData but just assigns it from `soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataLeft`, and if you look in the code will free that data for `soundStructArray[audioFile].audioDataLeft`